# How to Space Out 2 or more Sentences in Python?

Tags: python, web

```
def show_happiness():
    return("I am always super happy!" ) * 7


print(show_happiness())
```

when it prints there's no space between the sentences, the comma(,) shows up when it prints:

```
I am always super happy!I am always super happy!....so it needs to be:I am always super happy! I am always super happy!...etc!
```

Comment: There are a few ways. Like `" ".join(["I am always super happy!"] * 7)` and `("I am always super happy! " * 7).strip()`

Comment: Combining a list of strings should be covered in any tutorial on string processing.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea. Johnny Mopp's comment shows you how to do it without a function.

```
def show_happiness(repeats=7, phrase="I am always super happy!", add_space=True):
    if add_space:
        return (phrase +" ") * repeats
    else:
        return phrase * repeats
    


print(show_happiness())
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a few way to add space after string

```
("I am always super happy! " * 7).strip()
```

or

```
 ("I am always super happy! \t" * 7)
```